# Android In-App Purchase Downgrade-Upgrade

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription, android-inapp-purchase

I have integrated in-app in my Andorid application for single Product **productone**.

For that, I have created different Product-Ids in my Google Play Console as below :

**1. productone.monthly, 
2.productone.yearly**

As per my knowledge both the Product Ids will work independently since we can not group them together like it does in IOS-App Store.

Now, I have some doubts as below :

doubt 1 : If User purchased productone.yearly and payment done, What If User again by productone.monthly ?

and Vise Versa ?

I have to manage it from my side ? Like If I get that user purcahsed it for Yearly, I have to restrict the user to do not buy monthly subscription.

Please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Before coming to your two cases, note that you get all the purchase List from PurchaseResult object. So you get the purchase id lists. Now, there are two possible cases -

1. User has puchased your monthly product - 1. productone.monthly (if this is purchased, it will come in the list)

   In this case, you can show the billing dialog for yearly product. As you want your user to pay more for your app (Of course yearly plan will cost more for user and you are building your app to make money).
2. User has puchased your yearly product - 2. productone. yearly (if this is purchased, it will come in the list)

   In this case, you don't need to show billing dialog for monthly plan. As you don't want your user to pay less for your app (Don't allow plan downgrading).

Just in case you are thinking to allow both the options, follow this -

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#Allow-upgrade

Comment: Sir, If I move from Monthly to Yearly, and my product ids are two different ids there, So, It is possible that my monthly subscription is refunded and continues for Yearly subscription ? How that works ?

Comment: Can I group the products i.e. same product name with two durations yearly and monthly like it is in IOS ?

Comment: If you follow the link provided you will have an actual idea.  Please go through it.